# Tableless layout with two liquid columns (liquid - fixed - liquid)

Tags: html, layout, css, liquid-layout

So, this web application I'm working in haves three vertical columns expanding for the entire window height, and a footer `div` expanding for the entire width. The layout looks like this:

```
+|+
---
```

where `+` means a liquid column, `|` means a fixed column, and `-` the footer.

I've done the element positioning using absolute and relative positioning with some tweaks using jQuery. But I want to know if there is a way of doing this with CSS3 only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This neglects all browser not supporting the `box-orient` and `box-flex` properties (like IE).

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/p8vBC/11/

**CSS**:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

body > #main {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;

    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;

    display: box;
    box-orient: horizontal;

    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
}

footer {
    height: 100px;
    box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
}

aside {
    box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
}

#content {
    width: 400px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="main">
    <aside id="left"></aside>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <aside id="right"></aside>
</div>

<footer></footer>
```

Comment: I wish it was that easy... This doesn't work in IE at all, let alone older versions of FF. But that's why CSS3 + HTML5 makes web dev fun, as it works quite intuitively ;)

Comment: Actually, since this is an application (not a website), I can put some system requirements. For IE users we can force them to use Chrome Frame (or Chrome itself, for that matter). That's why I hate IE. A bunch of wonderful open source renderers and they stick with this obsolete trident engine.

Comment: But Trident *obviously* is the best. Lower on Acid3 the better ;)

Comment: That is Microsoft's perspective. :)